# How to use React TransitionMotion willEnter()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-motion

Using [React Motion's TransitionMotion](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion), I want to animate 1 or more boxes in and out. When a box enters the view, it's width and height should go from 0 pixels to 200 pixels and it's opacity should go from 0 to 1. When the box leaves the view, the reverse should happen (width/height = 0, opacity = 0)

I have tried to solve this problem here http://codepen.io/danijel/pen/RaboxO but my code is unable to transition the box in correctly. The box's style jumps immediately to a width/height of 200 pixels instead of transitioning in.

What is wrong with the code?

```
let Motion = ReactMotion.Motion
let TransitionMotion = ReactMotion.TransitionMotion
let spring = ReactMotion.spring
let presets = ReactMotion.presets

const Demo = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      items: []
    }
  },
  componentDidMount() {

    let ctr = 0

    setInterval(() => {
      ctr++
      console.log(ctr)
      if (ctr % 2 == 0) {
        this.setState({
          items: [{key: 'b', width: 200, height: 200, opacity: 1}], // fade box in
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          items: [], // fade box out
        });
      }

    }, 1000)
  },
  willLeave() {
    // triggered when c's gone. Keeping c until its width/height reach 0.
    return {width: spring(0), height: spring(0), opacity: spring(0)};
  },

  willEnter() {
    return {width: 0, height: 0, opacity: 1};
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <TransitionMotion
        willEnter={this.willEnter}
        willLeave={this.willLeave}
        defaultStyles={this.state.items.map(item => ({
          key: item.key,
          style: {
            width: 0, 
            height: 0,
            opacity: 0
          },
        }))}
        styles={this.state.items.map(item => ({
          key: item.key,
          style: {
            width: item.width, 
            height: item.height,
            opacity: item.opacity
          },
        }))}
        >
        {interpolatedStyles =>
          <div>
            {interpolatedStyles.map(config => {
              return <div key={config.key} style={{...config.style, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
                <div className="label">{config.style.width}</div>
              </div>
            })}
          </div>
        }
      </TransitionMotion>
    );
  },
});

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the **[documentation](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion#--styles-arraytransitionstyle--previousinterpolatedstyles-arraytransitionplainstyle--arraytransitionstyle)** of `styles` under the `TransitionMotion` section (and I don't claim to have understood all of it entirely :)):

> styles: ... an array of TransitionStyle ...

The key thing to note here is that there are 2 types of *style* objects that this library deals with (or at least this `TransitionMotion` part of it) and it calls them `TransitionStyle` and `TransitionPlainStyle`.

The previous values passed into `styles` attribute were of `TransitionPlainStyle`. Changing them to `TransitionStyle` *magically* starts animating the `Enter` sequence.

You can read more about 2 different types mentioned above over **[here](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion#props-2)**.

```
styles={this.state.items.map(item => ({
  key: item.key,
  style: {
    width: spring(item.width), 
    height: spring(item.height),
    opacity: spring(item.opacity)
  }
}))}
```

**[Forked codepen demo](http://codepen.io/tah_med/pen/bpddKZ?editors=0010)**.

Again, I do not fully understand the inner workings of it just yet. I just know that your `styles` had to be changed in the above way to make it work.

I will be happy if someone can educate me on this as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks Tahir.