# Change css and state before component unmount Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and i need to change CSS classes before component unmount but my component recieves new props before unmounting and the css effect doesn't appear any solution please .Thanks in advance

```
     getNext=()=>{

    this.setState({
        isCardFadeOut: true
    })
    this.secondCard.current.classList.remove('second-card')
    this.secondCard.current.classList.add('main-card')
    this.thirdCard.current.classList.remove('third-card')
    this.thirdCard.current.classList.add('second-card')
    this.props.parent.getNext()

}
```

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve by changing the css class before unmount?

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb kind of animation using pure css so i wanna make the animation part then call getNext from parent  :/ without using setTimeOut

Comment: Do you want to animate any component when your component is about to unmount and any other component is going to mount? Do you want to unmounth smoothly right?

Comment: yes that's right @MuhammadHaseeb

Comment: You can add the css class before it get mount, but it will be useless because it  gets deleted from the DOM so quickly that you will not be able to see the animation. I would recommend to use react-transition-group package for the animation that can be used to animate whenever your state or props changes. I can also create an example of that if you want to use that packege.

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb  I've seen it but my animation idea is very simple it's all about changing margins that's why i'm using pure css

Comment: Its not as simple as it looks like but if you want to want to do it with the native events, this should be the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40064249/react-animate-mount-and-unmount-of-a-single-component

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb thanks a million i'm gonna try it

Answer (score 0):

I used onTransitionEnd event listener to call

```
this.props.parent.getNext()
```

and on getNext() i made my css changes which include transition and that makes the function call synced like below:

```
 <div ref={this.thirdCard} 
      onTransitionEnd={this.handleGetNext} 
      className="content-card third-card"/>


 handleGetNext = () => {
        this.props.parent.getNext()
    }


 getNext = () => {

        this.firstCard.current.classList.add('card-fading')
        this.secondCard.current.classList.remove('second-card')
        this.secondCard.current.classList.add('main-card')
        this.thirdCard.current.classList.remove('third-card')
        this.thirdCard.current.classList.add('second-card')


    }
```